# How to extract part of file name of a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to extract part of the file name using Java code.

For example if the name of the file is --> `StudentInfo_Mike_Brown_Log.csv`

I want to be able to just extract what is between the first two `_`'s in the file name. Therefore in this case I would be extracting `Mike`

So far I am doing the following:

```
    String fileName = "C:\\User\\StudentInfo_Mike_Brown_Log.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    String extractedInfo= fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("_"), fileName.indexOf("."));
    System.out.println(extractedInfo);
```

This code currently gives me `_Mike_Brown_brown_Log` but I want to only print out `Mike`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `getName()` method from the `File` object to return just the name of the file (with extension but without trailing path) and than do a `split("_")` like @Chasmo mentioned.

E.g.

```
File input = new File(file);
String fileName = input.getName();

String[] partsOfName = fileName.split("_");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partsOfName));
```

Comment: A little flaw will be the last item, which will also contain the extension "Log.csv"

Comment: OK the problems for post of @chasmo will also be applicable to mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) with a Regex to split the String into substrings.

Here is an example:

```
final String fileName = "C:\\User\\StudentInfo_Mike_Brown_Log.csv";
final String[] split = fileName.split("_");
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

Comment: That would result in ```{"C:\\User\\StudentInfo", "Mike", "Brown", "Log.csv"}```

Comment: That's teh reason I only printed element at index `1`.

Comment: In case the OP wanted to have the first element (StudentInfo) as well, you should probably eliminate the ```C:\\User\\``` first.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 it ignores the first element, which achieves the same thing.

Comment: You would get runtime exception if string doesn't contain underscore.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    int indexOfFirstUnderscore = fileName.indexOf("_");
    int indexOfSecondUnderscore = fileName.indexOf("_", indexOfFirstUnderscore+2 );


    String extractedInfo= fileName.substring(indexOfFirstUnderscore+1 , indexOfSecondUnderscore );

    System.out.println(extractedInfo);
```

Comment: You wont get anything in the output i bet. You need indexOfFirstUnderscore + 1 in your second indexOf method  indexOfSecondUnderscore and in your substring you need to extract string from indexOfFirstUnderscore + 1. Also what if string doesnt contain _ at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf()`, in addition to `indexOf()`:

```
    String fileName = "C:\\User\\StudentInfo_Mike_Brown_Log.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    filename = file.getName();

    String extractedInfo= fileName.substring(
                             fileName.indexOf("_"),
                             fileName.lastIndexOf("_"));
    System.out.println(extractedInfo);
```

It is important to firstly call `file.getName()` so this method does not get confused with underscore '_' characters in the file path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will print "Mike_Brown"

Comment: Only Mike? No "Mike_Brown"? Oh, dear. I thought it would be more complete with the surname.

Answer (score 0):

Solved from the previous answer:

```
String fileName = "C:\\User\\StudentInfo_Mike_Brown_Log.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName); 
    fileName = file.getName();

    System.out.println(fileName.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method of String class:

```
    String fileName = "C:\\User\\StudentInfo_Mike_Brown_Log.csv";
    int indexOfUnderScore = fileName.indexOf("_");
    int indexOfSecondUnderScore = fileName.indexOf("_",
            indexOfUnderScore + 1);
    if (indexOfUnderScore < 0 || indexOfSecondUnderScore < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "string is not of the form string1_string2_ " + fileName);
    }
    System.out.println(fileName.substring(indexOfUnderScore + 1,
            indexOfSecondUnderScore));
```